# curl_formfree not working properly return error: SegFault

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am writing code to upload file on file server along with two other string variables as part of HTTP post request.

Idea to use multi interface here is to upload multiple file in future.

Libcurl version being used here is: 7.44

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

const auto TimeoutInMS = 1000;
const auto FileDescriptorZero = 0;

bool HTTPPostSuccessful(long httpResponseCode)
{
    bool httpRequestSuccessful = false;
    if (httpResponseCode == 200)
    {
        httpRequestSuccessful = true;
    }
    return httpRequestSuccessful;
}

size_t WriteCallback(void * buffer, size_t size, size_t count, void * userp)
{
    size_t numBytes = size * count;
    static_cast<std::string*>(userp)->append(static_cast<char*>(buffer), numBytes);
    return numBytes;
}

void HTTPPost(const std::string& value1, const std::string& value2, const std::string& filePath)
{
    struct curl_slist *pHTTPRequestHeaders = nullptr;
    struct curl_httppost* pFormpost = nullptr;
    struct curl_httppost* pLastptr = nullptr;
    uint16_t httpResponseCode = 0;
    int stillSendingFile = 0;
    CURL* pCurlEasyHandle = curl_easy_init();
    CURLM *pCurlMultiHandle = curl_multi_init();
    std::string responseData{};

    
    if (pCurlEasyHandle && pCurlMultiHandle)
    {
        pHTTPRequestHeaders = curl_slist_append(pHTTPRequestHeaders, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurlEasyHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, pHTTPRequestHeaders);
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurlEasyHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://http_.org/logs/readers");
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurlEasyHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        
        curl_formadd(&pFormpost, &pLastptr,
                     CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "fileName",
                     CURLFORM_FILE, filePath.c_str(),
                     CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "text/csv",
                     CURLFORM_END);
        
        curl_formadd(&pFormpost, &pLastptr,
                     CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "Value1",
                     CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, value1.c_str(),
                     CURLFORM_END);
        
        curl_formadd(&pFormpost, &pLastptr,
                     CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "Value2",
                     CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, value2.c_str(),
                     CURLFORM_END);
        
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurlEasyHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, pFormpost);
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurlEasyHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurlEasyHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &responseData);
        
        curl_multi_add_handle(pCurlMultiHandle, pCurlEasyHandle);
        
        do
        {
            curl_multi_perform(pCurlMultiHandle, &stillSendingFile);
            if (stillSendingFile)
            {
                curl_multi_wait(pCurlMultiHandle, nullptr, FileDescriptorZero, TimeoutInMS, nullptr);
            }
        }
        while(stillSendingFile);
        
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_getinfo(pCurlEasyHandle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpResponseCode);
        
        if (HTTPPostSuccessful(httpResponseCode) && res == CURLE_OK)
        {
            
            std::cout << "File sent Successfully, HTTP response code: " << httpResponseCode << ", ResponseData: "<< responseData<< std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Error during request: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << ", Failure HTTP response code: " << httpResponseCode << std::endl;
        }
        
        if (pCurlMultiHandle && pCurlEasyHandle)
        {
            std::cout << "Clean up for curl_multi_remove_handle " << std::endl;
            curl_multi_remove_handle(pCurlMultiHandle, pCurlEasyHandle);
        }
        
        if (pCurlEasyHandle)
        {
            std::cout << "Clean up for pCurlEasyHandle " << std::endl;
            curl_easy_cleanup(pCurlEasyHandle);
            pCurlEasyHandle = nullptr;
        }
        
        if (pCurlMultiHandle)
        {
            std::cout << "Clean up for pCurlMultiHandle " << std::endl;
            curl_multi_cleanup(pCurlMultiHandle);
            pCurlMultiHandle = nullptr;
        }
        
        if (pHTTPRequestHeaders)
        {
            std::cout << "Clean up pHTTPRequestHeaders " << std::endl;
            curl_slist_free_all(pHTTPRequestHeaders);
            pHTTPRequestHeaders = nullptr;
        }
        
        if (pFormpost)
        {
            std::cout << "Clean up pFormpost " << std::endl;
            curl_formfree(pFormpost);
            pFormpost = nullptr;
            pLastptr = nullptr;
        }
    }


}


bool UploadFile(const std::string& value1, const std::string& value2, const std::string& filePath)
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    HTTPPost(value1, value2, filePath);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return true;
}

int main ()
{
    UploadFile("1", "1", "/tmp/UploadFIle/testDoc.txt");
}
```

above code works fine in my machine, when I commit it on Jenkins build server, I get following error:

```
7: HTTPClient Initialization is successful.
7: * Could not resolve host: http_.org
7: * Closing connection 0
7: Error during request: No error, Failure HTTP response code: 0
7: Clean up for curl_multi_remove_handle 
7: Clean up for pCurlEasyHandle 
7: Clean up for pCurlMultiHandle 
7: Clean up pHTTPRequestHeaders 
7: Clean up pFormpost 
 7/30 Test  #7: **** ....................................***Exception: SegFault  0.29 sec
```

In Few cases also seeing following error:

```
8: HTTPClient Initialization is successful.
8: * Could not resolve host: http_.org
8: * Closing connection 0
8: Error during request: No error, Failure HTTP response code: 0
8: Clean up for curl_multi_remove_handle 
8: Clean up for pCurlEasyHandle 
8: Clean up for pCurlMultiHandle 
8: Clean up pHTTPRequestHeaders 
8: Clean up pFormpost 
8: ==11267== Invalid read of size 8
8: ==11267==    at 0x4E48018: curl_formfree (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0)
```

Can somebody please inform me what is wrong here, new to Curl.

Comment: Why do you use the deprecated API?

Comment: Tagged Valgrind but no Valgrind output?

Comment: Hi @273K, We have to use curl version 7.44 that is why, please let me know if there is any other way possible, within this libcurl version.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem but in general it's a good idea to destroy things in the reverse order of how they were created

Comment: HI @273K, Updated the code as you suggested, now instead of invalid free, i am seeing seg fault.

Comment: @273K, Yes on the same line with curl_formfree. Currently our server is not ready, so able to test only negative cases on jenkins server, this error i am getting in case when server URI is invalid and file is empty, I also tested the same code with URI: "https://httpbin.org/post" on my machine with empty file which works fine. I am getting the error only on jenkins build server when i commit my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue resulting in UB is in `WriteCallback`:

```
static_cast<std::string*>(userp)->append(static_cast<char*>(buffer), 0, numBytes);
```

You have chosen the overloaded member function

```
basic_string& append( const basic_string& str,
                      size_type pos, size_type count )
```

that creates `std::string` from a not null-terminated data in the `buffer`.

You should use the other overloaded member function

```
basic_string& append( const CharT* s, size_type count )
```

therefore the correct call is

```
static_cast<std::string*>(userp)->append(static_cast<char*>(buffer), numBytes);
```

The second issue is `uint16_t httpResponseCode`, whereas `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE` requires a pointer to a long value, you pass `&httpResponseCode`, a pointer to a short value, this is yet another UB. Particularly it corrupts data in the local variables, writes zeros in 2 or 6 bytes outside the `httpResponseCode` storage, probably in `pFormpost` bytes. It should be

```
long httpResponseCode = 0;
```